# I want to use a for loop to avoid duplicate IDs, but I can not get out of the loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I wrote the following code to avoid duplicate ID, but I can not get out of the for loop.

```
print $someid;
```

is Keep displaying 0.

```
<?php
        for (; ; ) {
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT * FROM user WHERE id = :id";
            $id =  sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $idcheck = $connect -> prepare($sql);
            $idcheck->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $idcheck -> execute();
            $someid = $idcheck -> rowCount();
            print $someid;
            if ($someid = 0) {
                break;
            } 
        }
?>
```

How can I get out of the loop only if there are no duplicates?

Comment: `$someid = 0` is an assignment, not a comparison …

Comment: `while(true)` is more common for infinite loops

Comment: @YourCommonSense are there any performance issues with `for(;;)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the if condition, you are not comparing the value with 0 instead assigning to it, Do this way,

```
<?php
        for (; ; ) {
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT * FROM user WHERE id = :id";
            $id =  sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $idcheck = $connect -> prepare($sql);
            $idcheck->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $idcheck -> execute();
            $someid = $idcheck -> rowCount();
            print $someid;
            if ($someid == 0) {
                break;
            } 
        }
?>
```

Comment: Oh, I was careless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the if you are assigning 0 to `$someid.` An assignment return the value that is assignment (0 in this case, that is evaluated as false).

Use `==` instead to compare two values.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
if ($someid = 0)
```

Should be

```
if ($someid == 0)
```

If condition check equal need two equals signs instead of one

Answer (score 0):

You will always receive row size as 1 because even if there are no duplicates, the column will show value 0.

You need to get the actual value from the column and then you will have to do the comparison. Moreover, you are assigning 0 instead of comparing it with zero.